# ES6 Javascript Import same js file under multiple names

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm working with ES6 and I want to import the same file as 2 different names.

```
import Contact from './Grid'
import Account from './Grid'
```

Is there a way that I can have grid named by both contact and account without webpack importing it multiple times?

Comment: Why don't you just alias the first import? `const Account = Contact`

Comment: What is 'importing it multiple times' supposed to mean? A module can be imported wherever needed but it will be evaluated once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> without webpack importing it multiple times?

Using two separate import statements will not execute the file multiple times. Once a file has been loaded once, its exported values are cached for use with later calls. Given that, the only reason to group it into one statement would be potential readability improvements. That said, to answer your question, you can do

```
import { 
  default as Contact,
  default as Account,
} from './Grid';
```

if you want. You could also potentially do

```
import Contact from './Grid'
const Account = Contact;
```

just note that it doesn't do *quite* the same thing in cases where there are circular dependencies in your modules.

Answer (score 0):

If in your Grid file you are exporting your desired object/function/etc. as the default export (see below), you can use whatever name you want when importing. An example if Grid is a function would be:

```
//Grid file
export default function Grid() {
  // your Grid info
}
```

and

```
//import file
import Contact from './Grid'
import Account from './Grid'
```

Comment: So you're saying that webpack will not import `'./Grid'` multiple times in that example?
I am already doing the export, but it's a class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but webpack should only bundle modules once regardless of how many times they're used/imported throughout your app. Are you worried about webpack including the Grid source multiple times in the build output file, or something else?

Comment: Yes I was, but I figured out that it does not.